# Bad indentation of a mapping entry in ... Action

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, serverless-framework

I'm building a serverless template to read an S3 bucket, but I'm getting this error when I run the command `serverless login` 
**Error** : `bad indentation of a mapping entry in "xxxx\serverless.yml" at line 12, column 15:
              Action:
                    ^`

```yaml
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

# you can overwrite defaults here
#  stage: dev
#  region: us-east-1

# you can add statements to the Lambda function's IAM Role here
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - s3:*
        Resource: ${self:custom.s3_role_resource}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Action` should be aligned with `Effect`

```
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - s3:*
    Resource: ${self:custom.s3_role_resource}
```